# convert List<Dictionary<string, string>> to Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have some data

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> data = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

And as a result i  need a Dictionary of dictionaries like

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> data2 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

How can I convert this?

Comment: What do you want to use as keys in the new dictionary?

Comment: as a key  i  want to use 1 value on each  Item from  data

Comment: Show some sample data would help.

Comment: So  i  found the answer, it is not preety  but it works.

Comment: foreach(Dictionary<string, string> item in data) {
                string title = null; 
                var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kp in item) {
                    if (kp.Key == "title")
                    {
                        title = kp.Value;
                    }
                    else {
                        dictionary.Add(kp.Key, kp.Value);
                    }
                }
                data2.Add(title, dictionary);
            }

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a `List` to a `Dictionary` with the [`ToDictionary` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.95).aspx), but you need to specify a key for each entry. For example, you can take an arbitrary value from the inner dictionary:

```
var data2 = data.ToDictionary(d => d.Values.First());
```

However, I smell an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) here.